# How to determine if the current route is active in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

**react v0.14.7** / **react-router: v2.0.1**

I have my Routes set up as follows:

```
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from "react-router"

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Index}/>
      <Route path="/locations" component={Locations}/>
      <Route path="/products" component={Products}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>, 
  document.getElementById('app'));
```

I'm trying to write a method in one of my React classes (created using the following API)

`export default class MyClass extends React.Component {...}`

...that determines if the current URL's path is a particular route's path.

For example. Assuming the current URL is `http://domain/products` then calling:

`isActive('/products')`

would return `TRUE`

I'm aware of React Router's `Link` object `activeClassName`. But I need to write something that looks this up programmatically in a different location to where I defined the `<link/>` objects.

Looking in `node_modules/react-router/` I can see `modules/isActive.js` that does what I need, however it's not `export`ed in `modules/index.js`, so i'm assuming I cannot access it?

I also see [from the API docs that there is an RouterContext isActive method](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#isactivepathorloc-indexonly), but again, I don't know how to call this?

Comment: `this.context.router.isActive` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Oleg, Seems not. I get a JS console error: "TypeError: this.context.router is undefined"

Comment: incredibly important information that you forgot to add: which version of react-router? (if 2.0, did you remember to [specify the context](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ConfirmingNavigation.md)?)

Comment: Sorry, yes. I'm using react-router v2.0.1

Answer (score 1):

OK thanks to Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans, I resolved the issue like so:

Changed create class API from:

```
export default class MyClass extends React.Component {

    ...  

}
```

to:

```
export default React.createClass({
    ...
})
```

And added the following `contextTypes` definition to the class:

```
export default React.createClass({

  contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
  },

  render(){

    console.log(this.context.router.isActive('/foo')); // Now works :)

    ...
  }

})
```

Comment: the usage of React.PropTypes will throw a warning with the newers version of React. see https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html